# Triggering click event PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to try and scrape a trivia question and its answer. With help from Stackoverflow. I have little understanding of Javascript so please explain what I'm doing wrong in details
The page is there:

```
http://www.buddytv.com/trivia/game-of-thrones-trivia.aspx
```

Here's the code:

```
  function click(el) {
   var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
   ev.initMouseEvent(
           "click",
           true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
           window, null,
           0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
           false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
           0 /*left*/, null
           );
   el.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }

  click('a[href="javascript:___gid_10(0)"]');
  answer = page.evaluate(function() {

   return  $('body').html();
  });
```

I'm trying to click on the first answer and return whatever the page returns after that (except it's returning NULL). Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: A string is being passed into the click method, not an actual element, so dispatchEvent is being called on a string, not an element on the page. You'll need to get a reference to the element somehow to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FAQ: why doesn't the page change *instantly* once I've dispatched my event?**

After you click you need to use `window.setTimeout` to check the changes made to the page some time *afterwards*. Say a second. Or 5. Because pages don't *instantly* change. They take time to load and render.

I want to *plaster* this answer all over the front page of the PhantomJS website.

**FAQ: I want to dispatch an event on my page. How?**

Well - you have to do the dispatch from within the `page.evaluate()` call. Otherwise you're just dispatching an event on PhantomJS itself. Which is pointless.

Comment: PP. is there any way to determine "how much" should we wait?

Comment: Unfortunately the shorter you wait the more CPU you use in loops - and PhantomJS does use a reasonable amount of CPU. I would think 250ms is adequate as humans wouldn't respond much quicker than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function click(el){
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        ev.initMouseEvent(
            "click",
            true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
            window, null,
            0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
            false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
            0 /*left*/, null
        );
        el.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
```

Comment: isn't that the exact same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PhantomJS's `sendEvent` to simulate a mouse-click, documentation here:

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html