# Test passing in Jasmine but failing in grunt-contrib-jasmine: document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

This test passes when I run it via a webbrowser (safari or chrome) but fails via grunt-contrib-jasmine.

```
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName('video')[0].click()'
```

strangely document.getElementsByClassName('video').length = 1, but document.getElementsByClassName('video')[0] === undefined

```
describe('ringing incomming', function (){
    var ringing_url = "ringing_payload"
    var webRtcUi = false;
    var accept = false;
    var hangup = false
    beforeEach(function (){
        accept = jasmine.createSpy('accept');
        hangup = jasmine.createSpy('hangup');
        webRtcUi = new WeemoWebRtcUi.WebRtcUi({dn: "wassupHomeBoy", accept: accept, hangup: hangup }, {legacy: false, uiRingToneUrl: ringing_url}, false);
        webRtcUi.ringing();
    });
    afterEach(function (){
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('incoming-call')[0]);
    });

    it('on accept clicked callobject accept called', function (){
        document.getElementsByClassName('video')[0].click();
        expect(accept).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the symptoms wrong.
It was actually the .click() function that does not exist in phantomjs. Object.keys(document.getElementsByClassName('video')[0]) returned data even though console.log was blank.

I solved the problem by using

```
function click(el){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    ev.initMouseEvent(
    "click",
        true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
        window, null,
        0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
        false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
        0 /*left*/, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}
```

found here:
 [Triggering click event PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468611/triggering-click-event-phantomjs)